# Python, how to undo a list within an other list

Tags: python

As a result of a function I have a list with the elements inside another list, and I would like to extract this elements to have a unique list.

This is the list I have:

```
[['word'], ['word'], ['word'], ['word']]
```

This is the list I would like to have:

```
['word', 'word', 'word', word']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```py
list = [['word'], ['word'], ['word']]
output = []
for entry in list:
    for word in entry:
        output.append(word)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

result = list(itertools.chain(*original_list))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure itertools offers a method specifically for this: `itertools.chain.from_iterable(original_list)`